# Conformational Analysis of Ethane and Butane

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, physical-chemistry

How does a condensed matter theorist explain conformations of Ethane and Butane using tools from Quantum field theory? If they don't how do they calculate energy differences and predict differences hinged on conformation? I am asking purely out of curiosity.  I don't have any pressing calculation due. I just want to know if this is one of those things that are just better left to chemists.

Comment: There are no QED effects worth mentioning in crude molecular effects like conformations. The only time you need QED to get it right is when you do extremely high precision atomic physics, and even then the effects will only matter for a few well chosen systems. Non-relativistic single particle can get this done just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use QFT to predict the lowest potential energy conformations of e.g. ethane and butane.

Quantum chemistry, in particular the Molecular Orbital and VSEPR models, allow chemists to determine the electron configurations of such molecules. The conformational isomer with minimum internal electrostatic repulsion, that is minimum potential energy, then becomes self-evident from visual inspection of the 3D electron density distribution of the molecule in question.